# Voyager dashboard has a blank and can not add widget to it

Tags: php, laravel, voyager

I install Laravel and Voyager for my project. But It have a problem, dashboard on /admin has a blank.
I try add a widget but it is not working.

This is tutorial I follow:
https://laravelvoyager.com/academy/widgets/

Here a screenshot of the dashboard

[image]

I hope my problem will be fixed soon.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your 'config/voyager.php' modify section

```
'widgets' => [
        'TCG\\Voyager\\Widgets\\UserDimmer',
    ],
```